# Add value only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
let kod = "";
$(".radOvladac").click(function(){
if($(this).is(':checked')){
  let value = $(this).val();
  kod = kod  + value;
  console.log(kod);
}

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ovladani">

                <input type="checkbox" value="-y1" class="regulaceTeploty">
                <h2>Tempeture regulation</h2>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="-a" class="radOvladac">Heater<br>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="-b" class="radOvladac">Ground heater 1<br>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="-c" class="radOvladac">Ground heater 2<br>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="-d" class="radOvladac">Funcoil<br>

              </div>
```

I have multiple checkboxes (around 20)

```
<input type="checkbox" value="-a" class="Configurator">Radiátory<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="-b" class="Configurator">Podlahové vodní<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="-c" class="Configurator">Podlahové el.<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="-d" class="Configurator">Funcoil<br>
```

If i check any, adds .val(); as string inside variable "kod" (code)

```
$(".radOvladac").click(function(){
if($(this).is(':checked')){
  let value = "";
  kod = kod + value;
  value = $(this).val();
  kod = kod + value;
  console.log(kod);
}
```

It adds up its value like "-a-a-a-a-b..." How can i toggle this value only once? Kod is global variable that cant be changed. If i check checkbox, it adds -a -> if i uncheck, it deletes -a and so on. I have been using -split, however that would be complicated.

Comment: where is element with class `radOvladac`

Comment: Why are you doing this twice -> `kod = kod + value;`  and what/where is `kod`?   Can you make your question into a snippet, it will help a lot.

Comment: What is `kod`.?

Comment: Kod is global variable that stores multiple strings. See snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understant from your question you need below solution i guess. Also i dont know what radOvladac is so have used input class hope it helps :)

```js
kod = "";
$(".Configurator").click(function() {
  let value = "";
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    kod = kod + value;
    value = $(this).val();
    kod = kod + value;
  } else {
    value = $(this).val();
    index = kod.indexOf(value);
    //console.log(index);
    kod = kod.slice(0, index)
  }
  console.log(kod);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="-a" class="Configurator">Radiátory<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="-b" class="Configurator">Podlahové vodní<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="-c" class="Configurator">Podlahové el.<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="-d" class="Configurator">Funcoil<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, this should do it?

```
$(".radOvladac").click(function(){
if($(this).is(':checked')){
  let value = $(this).val();
  kod = kod + value;
  console.log(kod);
} else {
  kod = kod.replace($(this).val(), "");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, its working. Im dumb begginner. Sorry. :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this... This will show all the checked items anytime.

```js
let kod = {};
$(".radOvladac").click(function(){
let val = $(this).is(':checked') ? $(this).val() : "";

kod["item" + $(this).val()] = val;

let finalVal = $.map(kod, function(v){
    return v;
}).join('')
alert(finalVal);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ovladani">

                <input type="checkbox" value="-y1" class="regulaceTeploty">
                <h2>Tempeture regulation</h2>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="-a" class="radOvladac">Heater<br>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="-b" class="radOvladac">Ground heater 1<br>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="-c" class="radOvladac">Ground heater 2<br>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="-d" class="radOvladac">Funcoil<br>

              </div>
```